# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties. Use Oracle on Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

i'm trying to build a solution for .NET 5.0, ORACLE, ASP.NET Identity with N-tier architecture.

Now i've this error

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
> properties:
> `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder,
> int, int)' and
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.OracleModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder,
> int, int)' ......EXAMPLE_SCHEMA_ContextModelSnapshot.cs

Error is in both **.UseIdentityColumns()** instructions

```
{
    [DbContext(typeof(EXAMPLE_SCHEMA_Context))]
    partial class EXAMPLE_SCHEMA_ContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder    modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder
                .HasDefaultSchema("TEST")
                **.UseIdentityColumns()**
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 30)
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.1");



            modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(10)")
                    **.UseIdentityColumn();**

                b.Property<string>("ClaimType")
                    .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2(2000)");

                b.Property<string>("ClaimValue")
                    .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2(2000)");

                b.Property<string>("RoleId")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2(450)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("RoleId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims");
            });


..........
```

Comment: It looks like you have references to both EF Core SQL Server and EF Core Oracle providers installed. If you are using Oracle, remove the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Nuget Package.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [steve-py](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423497/steve-py)

It was that problem but it's very strange that mechanism reported in the article clearly mentioned the use of that library.